# How to align Images properly in rows?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want six images to align properly, for example in two rows of three images, and be level. But they are not aligning, and some of them are not even the same size.

My intial issue was when making the screen smaller the images would fall into each other. That is not an issue now, but the images are not the same size and they do not align properly.

How do I align images properly in rows?

Here is my working code:

```css
#boxes .box img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Yosemite National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629233796529-4a04bf1aee52?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1287&q=80" alt="Yosemite">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Redwood National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582790670329-b14bf5c38562?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=735&q=80" alt="Redwood">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Joshua Tree National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1626008007279-f41981695728?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1374&q=80" alt="Joshua Tree">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Channel Islands National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629256299843-5fb1714fe067?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1287&q=80" alt="Channel Islands">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Seqouia National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535628169704-5d0b32718ee8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="Seqouia">
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <h3>Pinnacles National Park</h3>
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624244453711-e042e81529d9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="Pinnacles">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Use `#boxes { display: grid; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; }` and some grid auto layout properties.

Comment: I tried both grid-auto-rows  and grid-auto-columns and neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your CSS a little bit, separating the classes and defining another properties.

I recommend you see more about [Aligning items in a flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) because it's an essencial property when working with responsive design.

Also you can see more about [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.

```css
#boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
 }
.container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
 }
.box > img {
    object-fit: contain;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Yosemite National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629233796529-4a04bf1aee52?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Yosemite">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Redwood National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582790670329-b14bf5c38562?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Redwood">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Joshua Tree National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1626008007279-f41981695728?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Joshua Tree">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Channel Islands National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629256299843-5fb1714fe067?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Channel Islands">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Seqouia National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535628169704-5d0b32718ee8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Seqouia">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Pinnacles National Park</h3>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624244453711-e042e81529d9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&h=687&q=80" alt="Pinnacles">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're right I should I have been more specific with my initial post. But after looking at my site I think the response you provided works best. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

for 2 dimensional layouts it's better to use CSS Grid which is pretty cool and also simple.
to use CSS Grid you need to set your container display to grid.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

(height and width of images would be as big as the biggest one because justify-items and align-items by default are on stretch so it will give all images the same size but it may affect on your image quality because by stretching they wouldn't have proper ratio of width and height.)

you can also read grid documentation and use its other features to style it more specifically.